# Symfony2.7, having problems with a form collections field and Doctrine

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Blog entity which is supposed to have one Poll entity and each Poll entity has many Choice entities associated to it. I was trying to create an "Add/Edit Poll" form for the blog. In that form, in addition to the Poll form fields I want to have a field that allows you to add Choices (a simple text field each). I'm having trouble figuring out how I should code this so that it works well. The PollType form looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title', 'text');
    $builder->add('choices', 'collection', 
        array(
            'label_attr' => array(
                'style' => 'vertical-align: top;'
            ), 
            'type' => 'text', 
            'required' => false, 
            'allow_add' => true, 
            'allow_delete' => true, 
            'delete_empty' => true, 
            'attr' => array(
                'style' => 'display: inline-block; margin: 0 0 20px 20px; width: 200px;'
            )));
    $builder->add('description', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('rows' => 6)));
    $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Poll'));
    $builder->getForm();
}
```

Originally I had 'type' => new ChoiceType() with ChoiceType being:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('title', 'text');
}
```

But I had to remove all this because "Variable "expanded" does not exist in bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" error that I could not find any solution for. I changed the type to text but now I'm stumped as to how I would collect the data from each "choices" field, persist it to the Choices entity, and also associating all of them with the new Poll (which may not have been inserted yet so I don't have an ID to add to Choices->pollID). Is there a standard way for doing this kind of thing that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Poll entity and Choice entity, so it looks like this:

```
$builder->add('choice', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:Choice',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('choice.name', 'ASC');
    },
));
```

Also you must have OneToMany or ManyToMany association with your entities.

More about [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)